# USB error in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have a problem that when I connect my mobile phone to my laptop by USB to start run my app in android studio, 
can I get any help???

usb connect:

[image]

Comment: your device has sdk 17, your app requires 23. go to your build settings and lower the target sdk and min sdk from there and try again. ps. dont forget to sync, clean, rebuild your app

Comment: how I can lower the target sdk and min sdk, plz?

Comment: go to your build.gradle file and change compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0' minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23 these to your own sdk requirements which is 17 in this case. do googling for the rest of it.

Comment: Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-17' in: C:\Users\JUMAN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1

Comment: exactly! for that part you have to use GOOGLE. learn how to open the sdk manager on android studio, then download the sdk versions you will need which is 17 in this case. and good luck

Comment: you are welcome. just another tiny detail, be sure you have USB debugging enabled on your phone settings, either it says usb debugging or trust unknown sources. good luck again

Answer (score 0):

You have created the app with min SDK version 23 (as mentioned in the snapshot) but your device is working on a lower version of android. (17)  You can change the min SDK version from project properties or create a new application project with lower or equal version of android SDK than the android version installed on your device.

The version of SDK, you select, will work on any device having same or higher version of android OS installed.

Answer (score -1):

(1) You should try to restart your PC.
(2) you should enable USB debugging on your phone.

Comment: Enable USB debugging on your phone

Comment: I enable USB debugging on my phone and also not solve

Comment: I download SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones and also not solve

Comment: Download Genymotion for PC. It is faster and built for developers

Comment: I try but I have a problem with license

Comment: Genymotion requires no license if you register as a gamer/ perdonal